# Gravity Forms and CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress, integration

Anyone have success integrating Gravity Forms with CiviCRM? Alternatively is there another WP form plugin that works with WPML and CiviCRM.  A plugin would be great.  We are looking at the CiviCRM API, but hope to get advice from someone that has done this before.  Thanks.

Comment: I particularly like Caldera Forms (free), very powerful form builder, I'm currently working in integrating it with Civi, I'll post back here when I have something more robust to show

Answer (score 6):

There are currently two Wordpress integrations that I know of:

1) Contact Form 7 integration, developed by CiviCoop, [here](https://civicrm.org/blog/erikhommel/send-wordpress-contact-form-7-data-to-civicrm-with-api) more info about it, I haven't tried it yet but looks promising.

2) Gravity Forms integration (paid for add-on) developed by Civivip, link to their [shop](http://shop.civivip.com), it supports Contacts and Activities entities.

**Edit**

Here's the Caldera Forms integration that I'm working on (the one I mentioned in the comment), is still in progress but is usable, if anyone wants to try it I recommend doing it in test environment first.

Github repository: [caldera-forms-civicrm](https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm)

You will need the Caldera Forms plugin installed previously, and of course CiviCRM, for it to work.

Comment: Thank you.  I looked at Contact Form 7, but do not think this form tool is user friendly enough from my client.  I tried Civivip's product before, without success.  But will try again.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Nina Gonzalez I've updated the answer with a 3rd option, I would appreciate feedback if you give it a try.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei will look at Caldera Forms as an alternative, looks promising.

Answer (score 3):

We've had a lot of users adopting the Gravity Forms + CiviCRM integration and are looking to take it to the next level. (Thanks Andrei for referencing it.) Currently, as Andrei alluded to, it supports Contacts and Activities entities. This includes custom fields added to these entities and the ability to create relationships between multiple contacts as well as multiple types of contacts on form submission. We'd like to extend this to Events, Memberships, and Contributions but don't have an ETA yet. If anyone has had a chance to use it and has feedback, we'd love to hear it! [View specific GF Form integration details with screenshots here](http://shop.civivip.com/civi-plugins/gravity-forms-integration/).

Comment: Thank you Nathan, yes I purchased your product but had some trouble using it. I would like to try again.  Can you respond to my email and give me access to the download.  Would appreciate your help.

Comment: Just installed it and did my first test.  Works great!!!

Comment: Good to hear @NinaGonzalez! Let us know if you run into any bumps along the way. :)

Answer (score 3):

Though this question is a bit older: We have made very good experience with Calderaforms together with the [Caldera Forms CiviCRM integration Plugin mentioned above](https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm). However at some point we needed a bit more and thanks to the help of Jaap from CiviCoop there is now also a [integration of Caldera Forms with the CiviCRM Form Processor](https://github.com/civimrf/cf-civicrm-formprocessor) ready allowing more flexibility handling submissions, prefilling Calderaforms etc.