# Webform CiviCRM Integration

Tags: extension, webform-civicrm, cms-integration

I've found the extension "Webform CiviCRM Integration" is compatible with Drupal. But, I'm working with WordPress and need to register membership in a more flexible way than allowed by CiviCRM alone. 
Does anyone know whether Webform CiviCRM Integration works for WordPress?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have flagged this as a duplicate question of https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/787/webform-civicrm-equivalent-for-wordpress. also worth looking at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11947/gravity-forms-and-civicrm

Answer (score 1):

No - it won't work.

I think caldera forms may be the way to go on WP as far as forms go (although others will be better informed).

[civicrm-wp-member-sync](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-wp-member-sync/) may be the way forward - And Haystack (the developer) may have the best viewpoint ;)

Comment: I've have being reading about Caldera Forms, but I think it is just to create/update Contacts and to add relationship to other contact, including other entities as Groups, Tags and Activities. But, not sure if this plugin allow to create/update data in Membership entity. I would really grateful if anyone could let me know.

Comment: Hi Cristina, have you seen / read this? https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/wordpress/#civicrm-wordpress-member-sync

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm now working with Caldera Forms and CiviCRM WordPress Member Sync. But, before going further in my development, I would like to make sure if my assumptions are right. I'm trying to create a Form with all data of the contacts needed in my CiviCRM database. They will be a Household and the contacts belonging to this household with their relationships established. But, I will need this Household and its related contacts to be a member in CiviCRM, establishing the appropriate membership. Can "CiviCRM WordPress Member Sync" create this new Membership for the Household?